# A window appears and then disappears when clicking the "Authorize" button 

Tags: 11.10, gwibber

This is my first time using Gwibber, so I'm a little bit confused. I start it and try to add a new account for facebook, but when I click the "authorise" button, a window appears and disappears again. What is wrong? It's shown up every time I tried this and it's driving me crazy. Btw, i use Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, had the same issue when trying to create accounts for twitter or facebook. A later update fixed this issue and another issues related to correctly connecting to facebook.

Just update your 11.10 and you should be fine.

Here is a similar issue related to a previous version: https://bugs.launchpad.net/gwibber/+bug/422904 (Could not find the 11.10 issues) but I seen the one about facebook in 11.10 that got fixed and with it the bug you are referring to.